# Can Android Studio debug with aosp emulator

Tags: android-studio

I have sucessed build aosp with lunch aosp_x86_eng, I also can sucessed start the emulator from aosp, buy when I open Android Studio write a helloworld, I can not find the aosp device in "Run-->Select Device". but in the Logcat windows, I can see the log from aosp emulator, in "Tools--troubleshoot device connections" it also says have found the emulator-5554 device.

I have tried aosp 2.3/4.4/6.0, I have open "usb debugging" switch in setting and the helloworld project compile SDK version also lower than the emulator SDK version, but I can not deploy and debug the app with the emulator.
what is the problem? Can anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: Hi, what's the error you're having?

Comment: that i can not choose the emulator to deploy ,it do not show in the device list.